# Git GUI - How to remove folder when pushing

Tags: git, git-gui

I would like to push a project but one folder in my Git repository with Git GUI. How to automatically remove the folder each time I commit and push my project without remove it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore files or directories by creating a file called .gitignore. See [the Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) for more details on using this. This will affect git-gui automatically as well as all other git tools.